# Changing elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

Take the simplest case of indexing the following document in elasticsearch

```
{
  "name": "Mark",
  "age": 28
}
```

With automatic mapping the mapping for this index would now look like

```
"properties" : {
   "doc" : {
     "properties" : {
       "age" : { "type" : "long"},
       "name" : { "type" : "string"
    }
  }
},
```

But say I then wanted to allow the case where this document should be indexed

```
{
  "name": "Bill",
  "age": "seven"
}
```

If I try this the mapping does not update and elasticsearch throws an error since there is a conflict with the type of the age property. 
Is there any way to do this so both docs could be automatically indexed and consequently queryable?

Comment: Please follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999012/elastic-search-update-mappings/64979251#64979251

Answer (score 2):

Mappings are defined per type so what you could do is having two types in your index:

1. numeric
2. alphabetical

And split the documents according to the value in the age field. If you run a query you can query both types.

Comment: @MeiSign- How do i go about telling elasticsearch to `Consider everything but dates as strings`?

Comment: I never did that actually but I guess if you create the Index you could set the numeric detection to false for example:|http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_numeric_detection

Answer (score 1):

you can add new fields and update a mapping. But you cannot update a mapping.To do that you need to drop the index and create a new mapping and index the data..!

For more info refer this link [reference](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-to-update-a-mapping-td3707981.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change existing mapping.You can only add new field in it.
 Or you have to delete old mapping  & create a new mapping for that particular index.