# Elastic search update mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mappings created wrongly for an object in elastic search. Is there a way to update the mappings. The mapping has been created wrongly for type of the object(String instead of double).

Answer (score 1):

In general, the mapping for existing fields cannot be updated. There are some exceptions to this rule. For instance:

```
new properties can be added to Object datatype fields.
new multi-fields can be added to existing fields.
doc_values can be disabled, but not enabled.
the ignore_above parameter can be updated.
```

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

That's entirely possible, by `PUT`ting the new mapping over the existing one, [here are some examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html).

Please note, that you will probably need to reindex all your data after you have done this, because I don't think that ES can convert string indexes to double indexes. (what will instead happen is, that you won't find any document when you search in that field)

Answer (score 0):

PUT Mapping API allows you to add/modified datatype in an existing index.

```
PUT /assets/asset/_mapping
{  
  "properties": {
    "common_attributes.asset_id": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": { 
          "type":  "keyword",
          "doc_values": true,
          "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

After updating the mapping, update the existing documents using bulk Update API.

```
POST /_bulk
{"update":{"_id":"59519","_type":"asset","_index":"assets"}}
{"doc":{"facility_id":491},"detect_noop":false}
```

Note - Use 'detect_noop' for detecting noop update.